# How can I block custom applications using URL schemes in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

I have worked a bit with URL schemes and have managed to access a custom app that i created using another app. My requirement is to block my custom apps once the battery level goes less than a certain level.

Is there any way to do that? What data will I have to pass through the URL scheme?

By block i mean either disable or uninstall completely. Just seeking some control.

Comment: No need to yell in your title.

Comment: "HOW CAN I BLOCK CUSTOM APPLICATIONS USING URL SCHEMES IN IPHONE" <- by turning off CapsLock.

Comment: What do you mean by "block"? Do you want to send a kill signal to your application?

Comment: Fixed the title.  Maybe your question will get a little more (positive) attention. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely block your application from launching if it's being opened through URL scheme. I suggest checking whether your app is launched by opening a scheme and then just display an alert view with a notice that your app requires the phone to have more battery power (or be charging).

Comment: App is  not being launched by opening a scheme .I only want to know how to disable the app using url schemes.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use push notification, it can handle your requirement